# Python two sums in Leetcode

Tags: python

hello everyone i am new in python and i am solving a two sums problem in Leetcode 
HEre is description:
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

My code is here:

```
 def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    num=[]
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        index=  target-nums[i]
        if(index in nums):
            num.append(i)
    return num
```

but i got error while i press  submit button

```
Input [3,2,4] 6
Output
[0,1,2]
Expected
[1,2]
```

andi don't know why

Comment: Explanation for why you have `0` in your answer:  your logic says to subtract a value from the target (`6-3`) which gives you `3`, then you search the list for `3` and you find it, at position 0.  The problem description says to add two different items from the list, not to use the same item twice.

Comment: i understood my mistake, thanks, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    container = {}
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if target - num in container:
            return [container[target - num], i]
        container[num] = i
    return
```

Answer (score -3):

here you go !

```
nums = [3,2,4]
target = 6


def twoSum(nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        elem = target - nums[i]

        if elem in nums and elem != nums[i]:
            return [i, nums.index(elem)]

print(
    twoSum(nums, target)
)
```